# How to suppress WikiWord formatting for variables in Fitnesse

Tags: wiki, fitnesse

I am using the `${varname}` syntax to reference an environment variable in one of my Fitnesse tests, in the form of

```
| check | Project Name | ${PROJECT_NAME} |
```

Most of the time this works fine, but occasionally the value of the environment variable is (coincidentally) in WikiWord format, which screws up the test because Fitnesse is treating it as a page link:

```
| check | Project Name | MyTestProject[?] |
```

I've tried using the `!- -!` syntax to suppress the formatting, but that prevents the variable from being resolved.  Is there a way to suppress the wikiword formatting *after* the variable is resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use literal tables by adding `!` to the beginning of the first row:

```
!|check|project name|${PROJECT_NAME}|
```